# Issues in hide toolbar with ObservableScrollView of Android

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

Hello friends i want to hide my toolbar with `ObservableScrollView` when user scroll on screen.

Related screen layout appears as below

[image]

And my layout file is as below

main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/header_bg"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow" />
        <customedittext.RegularEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_search"
            style="@style/Edittext"
            android:background="@drawable/search_rect"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"
            android:hint="Search Product"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_12" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
          >

        <com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/scl_rels"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rel_pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                          >

                        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                            android:id="@+id/pager_introduction"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                            tools:listitem="@layout/pager_item" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:gravity="center|bottom"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/scl_ll"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_pager"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/ll_1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5dp"

                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <customtext.BoldText
                                android:id="@+id/txt_title1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_14"
                                android:text="DEAL OF THE DAY"
                                android:textColor="#333333"
                                 />

                            <customtext.RegularText
                                android:id="@+id/txt_1"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="right"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="VIEW ALL"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_10"
                                android:textColor="@color/blue_common"
                                 />
                        </LinearLayout>


                        <HorizontalScrollView
                            android:id="@+id/hor"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/search_rect"
                            android:scrollbars="none">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/ll_child"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
                        </HorizontalScrollView>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/ll_2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5dp"

                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <customtext.BoldText
                                android:id="@+id/txt_title2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_14"

                                android:text="FOOD AND NUTRITION"
                                android:textColor="#333333"
                                />

                            <customtext.RegularText
                                android:id="@+id/txt_2"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="right"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="VIEW ALL"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_10"
                                android:textColor="@color/blue_common"
                                 />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <HorizontalScrollView
                            android:id="@+id/hor1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/search_rect"

                            android:scrollbars="none">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/ll_child1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
                        </HorizontalScrollView>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/ll_3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5dp"

                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <customtext.BoldText
                                android:id="@+id/txt_title3"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_14"

                                android:text="HOME AND FURNITURE"
                                android:textColor="#333333"
                                 />

                            <customtext.RegularText
                                android:id="@+id/txt_3"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="right"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="VIEW ALL"
                                android:textColor="@color/blue_common"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_10" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <HorizontalScrollView
                            android:id="@+id/hor2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/search_rect"

                            android:scrollbars="none">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/ll_child3"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
                        </HorizontalScrollView>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/ll_4"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5dp"

                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <customtext.BoldText
                                android:id="@+id/txt_title4"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_14"

                                android:text="ADDTOBUY FASHION SALE"
                                android:textColor="#333333"
                                  />

                            <customtext.RegularText
                                android:id="@+id/txt_4"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="right"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="VIEW ALL"
                                android:textColor="@color/blue_common"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_10"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <HorizontalScrollView
                            android:id="@+id/hor3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                            android:background="@drawable/search_rect"
                            android:scrollbars="none">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/ll_child4"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
                        </HorizontalScrollView>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<!--<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />-->

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
     android:layerType="software"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>

<!--<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />-->
```

When i run above code then it hide `toolbar` but remain some space at bottom as below :

[image]

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: looks like your viewpager is hiding and the deal of the day textview, are u sure u are not setting visibility of viewpager to invisible

Comment: ankitagrawal: yes i m not setting visibility of viewpager